# tool to find transitive backward dependencies in java code

Tags: java, intellij-idea, dependencies, code-analysis, transitive-dependency

I need to find transitive backward dependencies , it looks like IntelliJ Idea does not do it - I use version Ultimate 2018.1

Example : class CC extends BB that implements AA , class EE has a field of class DD that has a field of class AA. So potentially EE depends on CC - an implementation of AA.

```
AA <-- DD <-- EE
^
|
|
BB
^
|
|
CC
```

Idea does not find any backward dependency on CC - same as "find usages - Alt-F7"

Is there a way to find what is need in Idea, or could you suggest a tool that does it ?

Comment: No, `EE` doesn’t depend on `CC` or even `AA` it just depends on `DD`.

Comment: Intellij doesn't offer tools for more comprehensive static code analysis. You could try https://jqassistant.org/

Answer (score 0):

Please see the answer by link: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360006440079-transitive-backward-dependencies. Thank you